# Using SQL to extract information for research from electronic patient records

Tags: sql

I am trying to get information from thousands of patient records from `sql`, stored in the '`comments`' column of the `Progress Note table` from our electronic patient records system.

Due to the sensitivity of the request and the issues with patient identifiable information, I only want to pull the necessary data from this '`comments`' column, without pulling additional and un-necessary information which would be a breach of patient data.

Within the '`comments`' column (which is a free text column) is included loads of text which is written about each patient when they see their Consultant, such as `diagnosis`, `medication` and `general notes`.

For my research, I only need to extract those patients where this 'comments' column includes the words:

> Mirtazapine, Shcizophrenia and bi-polar

These three words must be present in each of the comments columns per patient to be considered valid for research purposes.  So, if one of the patients comments includes two out of the three key words, I will not use it (and I don't wish to see it, as it will be deemed an un-necessary extraction) - I only want to see any '`comments`' which have ALL of these 3 key words.

Can anyone help??

Comment: What have you tried? Post some working query, does not matter it returns wrong result, is a start and maybe you are not far from the actual solution. Wich RDBMS are you using, MS SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, Postgre? Please retag your question. All these actions will help you to get better answers.

Comment: of course you are going to get better results if you spell schizophrenia corectly.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
select *
from yourtable t1
where exists (select *
              from yourtable t2
              where comments like '%Mirtazapine%'
                and t1.id = t2.id)
  and exists (select *
              from yourtable t2
              where comments like '%Shcizophrenia%'
                and t1.id = t2.id)
  and exists (select *
              from yourtable t2
              where comments like '%bi-polar%'
                and t1.id = t2.id)
```

Or:

```
select *
from yourtable t1
where comments like '%Mirtazapine%'
  and exists (select *
              from yourtable t2
              where comments like '%Shcizophrenia%'
                and t1.id = t2.id)
  and exists (select *
              from yourtable t2
              where comments like '%bi-polar%'
                and t1.id = t2.id)
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb1bf/4)